# How do I write the information from this web-scraper to a text file?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request # i use this one instead of urllib
import re
import sys
import bs4 as bs

f = open('recipe.txt', 'r')
for line in f.readlines():
    wholeline = line.strip()
    sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(wholeline).read()
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'html.parser')
    for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='nutritional_info'):
        outfile = open('C:/Diabetes Scraper/ingredients.txt', 'a')
        outfile.write(div.txt + '\n')
```

When I run this code it give me an error message saying:

```
 File "C:/Diabetes Scraper/stackoverflow_scraper.py", line 14, in <module>
    outfile.write(str(div.txt + '\n'))
builtins.TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

When I run:

```
outfile.write(str(div.txt))
```

it gives me a bunch of chinese symbols in the file.

When I run :

```
outfile.write(div.txt)
```

It gives me the error:

```
  File "C:/Diabetes Scraper/stackoverflow_scraper.py", line 14, in <module>
    outfile.write(div.txt)
builtins.TypeError: must be str, not None
```

So how do I fix this problem? Should I write it into another type of file or scrape the data some other way or...? 
An example link for scraping the data:

http://www.diabetes.org/mfa-recipes/recipes/2017-03-grilled-vegetable-sandwich.html

Comment: Shouldn't it be `outfile.write(div.text)`?

Comment: I tried that but it gave me an error look at code snippet above.

Comment: You tried with div.txt, it should be div.text

Comment: OMG i'm dumb. I tried it and it worked, thank you! And another thing:

Comment: When I go to the file it shows:

Comment: `Nutrition Facts

Serving Size: 1 sandwich 

Calories
135
Carbohydrate
17 g
Protein
6 g
Fat
6.0 g
Saturated Fat
1.5 g


Sugars
3 g
Dietary Fiber
3 g
Cholesterol
5 mg
Sodium
365 mg
Potassium
285 gm`

How do I strip the whitespace and make it look good?

Comment: Use regex  - `re.sub(r'\n\s*\n', r'\n\n', div.text.strip(), flags=re.M)` - It'll remove newlines, trailing characters and tabs.